# Create a new build rule for DockerHub repository via API calls

Tags: docker, api, github, dockerhub

I have a repository on DockerHub, which I have configured to hook up directly with my GitHub repo, so that a `git` commit will trigger the build of the Docker images.

I am looking to build multiple Docker images (e.g. `v1`, `v2` etc) for my product.

Now, I can see that DockerHub gives you the option to configure the "build rules" directly from the portal:

[image]

so right now, when I make changes to the `/releases/v1/Dockerfile`, the build will be triggered automatically.

Cool.

Going forward however, I expect to release `/releases/v2/Dockerfile` to my GitHub repo, and I would like for `v2` to be built automatically as well, without me having to create the "build rule" manually. Is there a way to create a "build rule" programmatically?

I'm looking to call the DockerHub API to create the build rule.
I've been through the documentation of the API here
https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/
but I couldn't find what I was after.

I would like to end up with:

[image]

where `v2` was created programmatically and **not** from the console.

Comment: Have you tried to use regexp and capture group in the Dockerfile location field ? According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#tag-and-branch-builds) you should be able to use the capture group of the source in the Docker Tag field — maybe it works too in others... If yes, you may want to change your workflow to use tags in the source type and capture groups variables in the others.

Comment: Even if I wanted to do that, I'd like to know how to setup a build rule through API calls

Answer (score 0):

Docker Hub is following the git conventions where you wouldn't normally put different versions of the application in the same git commit. Instead, you would use separate branches and tags for different versions of your code. If you follow that git convention, then you can tag your resulting image based on the regex on the branch or tag. E.g.

- Source Type: `Branch`
- Source: `/^v([0-9.]+)$/`
- Docker Tag: `v{\1}`

Then you can build within a branch called `v1.1` (or any other version number) and the docker image will be tagged `v1.1`. To pull out just the first number of the tag, that would look like:

- Source Type: `Tag`
- Source: `/^v([0-9]+)[0-9.]*$/`
- Docker Tag: `v{\1}`

Which would convert a tag with a version number like `v10.1.2` into a docker tag of `v10` (only numbers before the `.` are matched in the first part of the regex).

For more details on their build rules, see:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#set-up-build-rules

Regarding the API, while the registry itself has a [documented API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/), and Hub has an [API for Hub in beta](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/api/latest), neither of these exposes the build settings. You could try to capture the calls by sniffing the browser traffic and replicating it in your app, but Docker could modify those calls at any time since they don't support an API for that.

Comment: Right, but this doesn't resolve the actual question. I'm looking for a way to create a build rule through API calls.

Comment: @Paolo not sure you saw the last paragraph. Sometimes "the vendor didn't implement that" is the answer even if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the last paragraph. There's already an existing library which seemed to work in the past https://github.com/RyanTheAllmighty/Docker-Hub-API despite "the vendor not having implemented", so there could be a solution now too.

Comment: @Paolo "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" is one of the community specific reasons to close a question here. I'm focusing on how to use the vendor's tool as they've provided it.

Comment: And that's completely reasonable. But I'd like to see if someone else can provide me with a solution